# pasting the first row into a new column - without pasting all other rows

Tags: r, list, dataframe, purrr

I have a number of lists and I want to paste everything in the first row (which I do not need but also do not want to get rid of it) such that the data:

```
# A tibble: 4 x 7
  financialVariable Currency `2019`   `2020`    `2021`    `2022`    `2023`   
  <chr>             <chr>    <chr>    <chr>     <chr>     <chr>     <chr>    
1 Ventas Cliente    NA       98716127 1477902   1970536   2955805   4433708  
2 Revenue           €        987,161  1,477,902 1,970,536 2,955,805 4,433,708
3 Expenditure       €        890,623  1,337,031 1,732,873 2,569,122 3,829,434
4 Profit (Loss)     €        96,538   140,871   237,663   386,683   604,274
```

Becomes:

```
  financialVariable Currency `2019`   `2020`    `2021`    `2022`    `2023`      New col
  <chr>             <chr>    <chr>    <chr>     <chr>     <chr>     <chr>    
1                                                                               c(Ventas Cliente|98716127|1477902|1970536|2955805|4433708)
2 Revenue           €        987,161  1,477,902 1,970,536 2,955,805 4,433,708
3 Expenditure       €        890,623  1,337,031 1,732,873 2,569,122 3,829,434
4 Profit (Loss)     €        96,538   140,871   237,663   386,683   604,274
```

So the first row is just pasted together into a new column separated by `|`. I thought about using: `group_by(.x, financialVariable) %>% summarise(., paste(., collapse = "|"))` but this pastes all of the rows into a single column and I only want the first row.

Code:

```
myList %>%  
   map(.,  ~separate(.x, financialVariable, into = c("financialVariable", "Currency"), "\n"))
```

Data:

```
myList <- list(company1 = structure(list(financialVariable = c("Ventas Cliente", 
"Revenue\n\200", "Expenditure\n\200", "Profit (Loss)\n\200"), 
    `2019` = c("98716127", "987,161", "890,623", "96,538"), `2020` = c("1477902", 
    "1,477,902", "1,337,031", "140,871"), `2021` = c("1970536", 
    "1,970,536", "1,732,873", "237,663"), `2022` = c("2955805", 
    "2,955,805", "2,569,122", "386,683"), `2023` = c("4433708", 
    "4,433,708", "3,829,434", "604,274")), row.names = c(NA, 
-4L), groups = structure(list(financialVariable = c("Expenditure\n\200", 
"Profit (Loss)\n\200", "Revenue\n\200", "Ventas Cliente"), .rows = structure(list(
    3L, 4L, 2L, 1L), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
"vctrs_vctr", "list"))), row.names = c(NA, 4L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = TRUE), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame")), company11 = structure(list(financialVariable = c("B2C and B2B Sales", 
"Revenue\nCHF", "Expenditure\nCHF", "Profit (Loss)\nCHF"), `2019` = c("2", 
"69,000", "187,000", "-118,000"), `2020` = c("2", "170,000", 
"556,000", "-386,000"), `2021` = c("2", "506,000", "1,102,000", 
"-596,000"), `2022` = c("2", "1,269,000", "2,013,000", "-744,000"
), `2023` = c("2", "3,110,000", "3,761,000", "-651,000")), row.names = c(NA, 
-4L), groups = structure(list(financialVariable = c("B2C and B2B Sales", 
"Expenditure\nCHF", "Profit (Loss)\nCHF", "Revenue\nCHF"), .rows = structure(list(
    1L, 3L, 4L, 2L), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
"vctrs_vctr", "list"))), row.names = c(NA, 4L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = TRUE), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame")), company7 = structure(list(financialVariable = c("0", 
"Revenue\n£", "Expenditure\n£", "Profit (Loss)\n£"), `2019` = c("0", 
"0", "0", "0"), `2020` = c("0", "0", "0", "0")), row.names = c(NA, 
-4L), groups = structure(list(financialVariable = c("0", "Expenditure\n£", 
"Profit (Loss)\n£", "Revenue\n£"), .rows = structure(list(1L, 
    3L, 4L, 2L), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
"vctrs_vctr", "list"))), row.names = c(NA, 4L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = TRUE), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame")))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems like a bad idea... but here's a way to do it.

```
lapply(myList, function(x) {
  new_val = do.call(paste, c(x[1, ], sep = "|"))
  x[1, ] = NA
  x$NewCol = NA
  x$NewCol[1] = new_val
  x
})
# $company1
# # A tibble: 4 x 7
# # Groups:   financialVariable [4]
#   financialVariable  `2019`  `2020`    `2021`   `2022`   `2023`   NewCol                                    
#   <chr>              <chr>   <chr>     <chr>    <chr>    <chr>    <chr>                                     
# 1  NA                NA      NA        NA       NA       NA       Ventas Cliente|98716127|1477902|1970536|2~
# 2 "Revenue\n€"       987,161 1,477,902 1,970,5~ 2,955,8~ 4,433,7~ NA                                        
# 3 "Expenditure\n€"   890,623 1,337,031 1,732,8~ 2,569,1~ 3,829,4~ NA                                        
# 4 "Profit (Loss)\n€" 96,538  140,871   237,663  386,683  604,274  NA                                        
# 
# $company11
# # A tibble: 4 x 7
# # Groups:   financialVariable [4]
#   financialVariable    `2019`   `2020`   `2021`    `2022`    `2023`    NewCol                     
#   <chr>                <chr>    <chr>    <chr>     <chr>     <chr>     <chr>                      
# 1  NA                  NA       NA       NA        NA        NA        B2C and B2B Sales|2|2|2|2|2
# 2 "Revenue\nCHF"       69,000   170,000  506,000   1,269,000 3,110,000 NA                         
# 3 "Expenditure\nCHF"   187,000  556,000  1,102,000 2,013,000 3,761,000 NA                         
# 4 "Profit (Loss)\nCHF" -118,000 -386,000 -596,000  -744,000  -651,000  NA                         
# 
# $company7
# # A tibble: 4 x 4
# # Groups:   financialVariable [4]
#   financialVariable  `2019` `2020` NewCol
#   <chr>              <chr>  <chr>  <chr> 
# 1  NA                NA     NA     0|0|0 
# 2 "Revenue\n£"       0      0      NA    
# 3 "Expenditure\n£"   0      0      NA    
# 4 "Profit (Loss)\n£" 0      0      NA
```

If you tell us why you're doing this, we may be able to help you find a better way to accomplish your goal.

Comment: Gregor, is there a difference between lapply(lapply(lapply(myList, function(x) x[1,]), as.character), paste0, collapse = '|') and lapply(myList, function(x) do.call(paste, c(x[1, ], sep = "|"))) , I tried with first option in your code but my results are different from yours. Does do.call return a vector for each run of lapply where as my code returns a list in place of a vector as above?

Comment: `lapply` always returns a `list`. `do.call` returns whatever the inner function returns - in this case `paste` returns a `character` vector.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The reason why I am doing it is because always the first row of each of the list of data frames contain information that I don't really need but I just do not want to throw it away since it might be valuable later on.

Comment: I would recommend putting it somewhere else rather than introducing a weird blank row and a new almost-always blank column. You could, for example,  extract the first rows, keep them separate and delete them from the originals: `firsts = lapply(myList, head, 1)`, `no_firsts = lapply(myList, tail, -1)`. You keep the info that way without creating weird data frames and concatenating things in an unusual way.

Comment: Thanks, I went with your suggestion for using `head, 1` and `tail, -1`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one possibility using an anonymous function:

```
myList %>%
  map(function(x){
    nc <- x %>% ungroup() %>% slice(1) %>% gather(date, val, -1) %>% pull(val) %>% paste0(collapse = "|")
    x %>% ungroup %>% 
    mutate(newcol = if_else(1:n() == 1, nc, NA_character_))
  })
```

Answer (score 1):

here is an option with `reduce` and `map`.  We loop over the `list` with `map`, `ungroup` to remove the group attributes, then use `case_when` to create a logical index to paste (`str_c`) only the first row.  By default, the other elements will be filled by `NA`

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(stringr)
map(myList, ~
        .x %>%
             ungroup  %>% 
              mutate(newcol = case_when(row_number() == 1
                 ~ reduce(cur_data(), str_c, sep="|"))))
```

-output

```
#company1
# A tibble: 4 x 7
#  financialVariable     `2019`   `2020`    `2021`    `2022`    `2023`   newcol                                           
#  <chr>                 <chr>    <chr>     <chr>     <chr>     <chr>    <chr>                                            
#1 "Ventas Cliente"      98716127 1477902   1970536   2955805   4433708  Ventas Cliente|98716127|1477902|1970536|2955805|…
#2 "Revenue\n\x80"       987,161  1,477,902 1,970,536 2,955,805 4,433,7… <NA>                                             
#3 "Expenditure\n\x80"   890,623  1,337,031 1,732,873 2,569,122 3,829,4… <NA>                                             
#4 "Profit (Loss)\n\x80" 96,538   140,871   237,663   386,683   604,274  <NA>                                             

#$company11
# A tibble: 4 x 7
#  financialVariable    `2019`   `2020`   `2021`    `2022`    `2023`    newcol                     
#  <chr>                <chr>    <chr>    <chr>     <chr>     <chr>     <chr>                      
#1 "B2C and B2B Sales"  2        2        2         2         2         B2C and B2B Sales|2|2|2|2|2
#2 "Revenue\nCHF"       69,000   170,000  506,000   1,269,000 3,110,000 <NA>                       
#3 "Expenditure\nCHF"   187,000  556,000  1,102,000 2,013,000 3,761,000 <NA>                       
#4 "Profit (Loss)\nCHF" -118,000 -386,000 -596,000  -744,000  -651,000  <NA>                       

#$company7
# A tibble: 4 x 4
#  financialVariable  `2019` `2020` newcol
#  <chr>              <chr>  <chr>  <chr> 
#1 "0"                0      0      0|0|0 
#2 "Revenue\n£"       0      0      <NA>  
#3 "Expenditure\n£"   0      0      <NA>  
#4 "Profit (Loss)\n£" 0      0      <NA>
```